# Why is my string showing weird characters instead of 'ñ'?

Tags: java, json, encryption

I´ve to consume a rest service to send mails, before consuming the service I´ve to create a json and encrypt it. So when I launch my rest client from a main class the 'ñ' character from the subject appears fine, but if I launch the same code from a struts action I get a weird character I compare the encrypted string from both scenarios and in both cases the encrypted String is different.
Here is my code where I receive the info put it in a json and encrypt it:

```
 public boolean enviarCorreo(String to, String body, subject) throws InvalidKeyException,
    IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Correo correoDTO = new Correo();
    correoDTO.setTo(to);
    correoDTO.setBodyHtml(body);
    String szUT8 = "";
        try {
            byte[] b1;
            b1 = subject.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(b1.toString());

            szUT8 = new String(b1, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(szUT8);              
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    correoDTO.setSubject(szUT8);
    String correoNoEncriptado = gson.toJson(correoDTO, Correo.class);
    String encryptedString = SymmetricEncryptionUtility
            .encrypt(correoNoEncriptado);
    String urlStr = "http://localhost:8080/correos/restFull/v1.0/generico/genera";
    String[] paramName = new String[1];
    paramName[0] = "jsonParams";
    String[] paramVal = new String[1];
    paramVal[0] = encryptedString;
    String salida = "";
    try {
        salida = httpPost(urlStr, paramName, paramVal);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RespuestaCorreo r = gson.fromJson(salida, RespuestaCorreo.class);
    return r.isSuccess();
}
```

What Mark said did the trick. In my encryption method I change from

```
byte[] stringBytes = message.getBytes();
```

to

```
byte[] stringBytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Because you're using the wrong encoding.

Comment: where am I using the wrong encoding. I already tryied to change my subject string to an utf-8 and that didn´t work either.

Comment: In the code that converts to/from bytes, which you have not showed us.

Comment: If you are encrypting securely, the encrypted string should be different every time, even if the unencrypted string is identical. So, that by itself might be meaningless. What server are you using to run your Struts(2?) action? Is the form action GET or POST? There are server-specific configuration properties that govern the encoding of URL parameters, since the specification isn't clear.

Comment: Can you pass correoNoEncriptado.getBytes("UTF8") into the SymmetricEncryptionUtility encrypt method?

Comment: my struts is running in tomcat 7 and I am launching a submit with a post

Comment: What Mark said did the trick. In my encryption method I change from byte[] stringBytes = message.getBytes(); to byte[] stringBytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");

Comment: @linker85 Could you update the question so that Mark (or SLaks or erickson) can post the answer?